# How do I present the task output in the current editor or a new editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'd like to run a task and present the output in the current open editor or a new editor. I'd prefer not to create a temporary file and trigger opening it.

Comment: and what would you like to happen to the existing content in the editor? wiped? new content appended?

Comment: It’s fine to wipe the contents.

Comment: what's the reasoning for this? would it solve your problem to just expand the output window to take up the whole editor space?

Comment: Sure. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to do this.

If you just want to get the terminal to show in the whole editor area, as a workaround, you could just expand the panel. In the panel's top right corner, there's an up-arrow button that will maximize the panel size, or you can use the `View: Toggle Maximized Panel` command in the command palette.

I was hoping there'd be some way to do something similar to the Output panel, which has a feature to open the output content in an editor tab ("Open Log Output File" button), but from some basic googling, it doesn't look like there's a way to get task output to go into the Output panel instead of the terminal panel.

I suppose you could also right click in the integrated terminal, select all, then right click again, copy, and then paste into a new editor tab.